Undefined external "f_open" reffered in main , FATF library not recognised?
Hi all im trying to set up an SPI interface between an MSP430 FR4133 and an external SD Card Reader. I am coming across these errors
Error[e46]: Undefined external "f_open" referred in main (C:\Users\****\Documents\SPI_Code\Debug\Obj\main.r43).

However i am unsure as to why these are being undefined as i have included all the FatF libraries needed within my workspace on IAR and have included them in my main, i know this is a simple problem but im struggling to figure out why these errors are occuring.
Here is my implementation of the functions and the headers.
#include "msp430.h"
#include "msp430_spi.h"  // Include your SPI library
#include "ff.h"         // Include FatFs library for SD card access
#include "diskio.h"     // Include low-level disk I/O functions
#include "userconfig.h"
#include "stdio.h"


#define BUFFER_SIZE 512  // Define buffer size for reading data from SD card
#define SPI_CS BIT3  // Chip select pin

#define CMD0 0x40
#define CMD8 0x48
#define ACMD41  (41 | 0x80)

#define R1_IDLE_STATE 0x01
#define CMD58 0x3A

// Function prototypes
uint8_t send_command(uint8_t cmd, uint32_t arg);
uint8_t read_response(uint8_t *response, uint8_t num_bytes);


// Function prototypes
void sd_card_init();

int main(void) {
    FRESULT result;          // FatFs function result
    FATFS fs;                // File system object
    FIL file;                // File object
    BYTE buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];  // Data buffer for reading from file

    // Disable watchdog timer
    WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;

    // Initialize MSP430 SPI
    spi_init();

    // Initialize SD card
    sd_card_init();

    // Mount the SD card
    result = f_mount(&fs, "", 0);
    if (result != FR_OK) {
        // Error handling
        return 1;
    }

    // Open the text file for reading
    result = f_open(&file, "Test.txt", FA_READ);
    if (result != FR_OK) {
        // Error handling
        return 1;
    }

    // Read data from the file
    UINT bytesRead;
    result = f_read(&file, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, &bytesRead);
    if (result != FR_OK) {
        // Error handling
        f_close(&file);
        return 1;
    }

    // Close the file
    f_close(&file);

    // Process the data read from the file
    // For example, you can print it to the console
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++) {
        putchar(buffer[i]);  // Assuming UART is used for output
    }

    // End of program
    return 0;
}

// Initialize SD card
void sd_card_init() {
    // Chip select low to select SD card
    P1OUT &= ~SPI_CS;

    // Delay for at least 74 clock cycles (about 1 ms)
    __delay_cycles(1000);

    // Send CMD0 (GO_IDLE_STATE) command
    send_command(CMD0, 0);

    // Send CMD8 (SEND_IF_COND) command
    send_command(CMD8, 0x000001AA);  // CMD8 with argument 0x1AA (voltage range 2.7-3.6V)

    // Read R7 response to CMD8
    uint8_t response[5];
    if (read_response(response, 5) != 0) {
        // Error handling
        return;
    }

    // Verify that SD card is version 2.x and voltage range is supported
    if ((response[2] != 0x01) || (response[3] != 0xAA)) {
        // Error handling
        return;
    }

    // Send ACMD41 (SD_SEND_OP_COND) command until card is ready
    // (loop until card returns R1_IDLE_STATE indicating initialization complete)
    while (send_command(ACMD41, 0) != R1_IDLE_STATE);

    // Send CMD58 (READ_OCR) command to read OCR register
    send_command(CMD58, 0);

    // Read R3 response to CMD58
    if (read_response(response, 5) != 0) {
        // Error handling
        return;
    }

    // Verify SDHC or SDXC card (check CCS bit in OCR)
    if (response[1] & 0x40) {
        // SDHC or SDXC card detected
    } else {
        // Standard capacity SD card detected
    }

    // Chip select high to deselect SD card
    P1OUT |= SPI_CS;
}


This is a linker error. Your code finds the requisite .h file just fine. What command are you using to link the program to the library? Do you have the correct -l and/or -L options?

How you compile your code? Please send directory structure of your code and its Makefile or CMakeLists.txt. You must add FatFS source repo to your project or use it as statically linked library as @Vraig Estey said.

Hi both, im pretty sure i have correctly linked all the files which come with the FATF32 download, i havent seen any .src directories which also need to be added. Regarding the makefile / cmakelists.txt im making all my projects via IAR and im pretty sure that makes these for you?

If all object files are there and you pass them to the linker, please re-order linker arguments, as I saw this: gcc -o execname -llib1 -llib2 gives error to me and gcc -llib1 -llib2 -o execname was correct or vise vera. And in clean compile of your code, please check IAR compile messages (compile and link commands executed) and post here.
